# (XeLaTeX) How to change chaptername (whichever language one uses)?

Tags: xetex, chapters, naming

Having come across a few threads and supposedly relevant or relevantly effective websites, I still have not found the answer to my question. After trial and error and having read things here or there, it's about time the matter is solved once and for all.

It concerns changing the word „Chapter” (or whichever other equivalent in another language), while using XeLaTeX. First, I used, e.g.:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Some Name}
```

As it did not work, I came across some source implying one should perhaps consider *babel* and its presence, so I put that command up there just after the *document command* in the preamble. Well, it did not work. Moreover, in my case I am using *polyglossia*, so must I perhaps somehow consider it in this matter (perhaps somewhat similarly to the consideration of babel)?

What is the quick and clean solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: Well, `polyglossia` *will* change the 'chapter name' according to the language declared by `\setmainlanguage`. If and why it isn't in your case is impossible to tell since you have not provided a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) for others to test. This example starts with `\documentclass` and goes down to `\end{document}`, but doesn't include things unrelated to the problem (e.g., this question does not need `amsmath` or `tabularx` or etc.).

Comment: @jon: Yes, I did not provide a minimal working example, because I thought it was irrelevant or unnecessary, because it seemed to me as though the answer to the question could be known without a minimal working example. I hope I will be able to provide one soon. (I will have to plan that due to time and the like.)

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks. My answer to jon would apply here too. I will try to provide a working example, though I thought it was unnecessary.

Comment: Normally, your command should have worked, so there's probably something else  in your preamble. However, try loading `etoolbox` and code `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Some Name}}`.

Comment: i guess the problem with the order. if you use `\chaptername` before setting `\setdefaultlanguage{}` english will appear.